# Problem with js/index.php

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with my javascript/PHP files.

If I open example.com/js/index.php

Then instead of the normal output it opens the file with all the content rather then executing it.

Does anybody know what the issue could be?

Other .php files get executed normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete Mukesh answer if you are runing `nginx` that means you may have a configuration issue.
You have to tell `nginx` to execute `PHP files` as it.
Here you can find your answer solved with example :
- https://serverfault.com/a/322023
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26668444/3531064

Answer (score 1):

- Check if PHP is installed and running.
- Make sure you are not using short open tags (`<?`) instead of `<?php`

Here's a similar issue: [PHP code is not being executed (I can see it on source code of page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page)